# java.lang.SecurityException: MODE_WORLD_READABLE

Tags: android, listview, sharedpreferences, android-gridview

I'm not using this flag `MODE_WORLD_READABLE` in my application but still, I get this exception? Is there any other reason for this `exception`, or this is me doing something wrong?

This is my logic for switching between `listview` to `gridview`, I set an `int` flag for them and save/retrive them in/from shared preferences:

```
private int currentViewMode = 0 ;
static final int VIEW_MODE_LISTVIEW = 0;
static final int VIEW_MODE_GRIDVIEW = 1;
boolean isGridView;
```

In onCreate:

```
currentViewMode = sharedPreferences.getInt("currentViewMode",VIEW_MODE_LISTVIEW);
```

And my swichView method:

```
    private void switchView() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = 
                        activity.getSharedPreferences("localGridCount",currentViewMode);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

    if (VIEW_MODE_LISTVIEW == currentViewMode){
        // ListView
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new 
                       GridLayoutManager(activity, 1, GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        gridCount = 1;
        editor.putInt("localGridValue", gridCount);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }else{
        // GridView
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new 
                       GridLayoutManager(activity, 2, GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        gridCount = 2;
        editor.putInt("localGridValue", gridCount);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    editor.apply();
}
```

And this is the full exception I get(Just in Nougat):
[Long_Exception_Link](https://pastebin.com/EHPNKTfG)

Comment: Try to use getDefaultSharedPreferences(activity) instead of 
                        activity.getSharedPreferences("localGridCount",currentViewMode);

Comment: @Majid Did u use VIEW_MODE_GRIDVIEW anywhere in your code?

Comment: @Raghavendra yes, to handle the switch I have two menu items on my action bar, the use of `VIEW_MODE_GRIDVIEW` is in `onOptionsItemSelected`

Comment: Why are you passing `currentViewMode` into `getSharedPreferences()`?

Comment: @CommonsWare I there difference `0` or `currentViewMode` ? , your are right anyway I should not to

Comment: You are the one defining the value of `currentViewMode`, not me.

Comment: @CommonsWare  I'm sorry, I misunderstand your question "Why are you passing currentViewMode...", I meant difference between `Context.AnyMODE` and `currentViewMode`

Comment: Rather than typing in `Context.MODE_PRIVATE`, you typed in `currentViewMode`. Why did you do this? The value for the second parameter to `getSharedPreferences()` should always be `Context.MODE_PRIVATE`. It should never vary, and I have no idea why it would be based on some sort of a "view mode".

Comment: @CommonsWare  It was completely unintentionally, and that was throwing the exception, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like in your code you have used **VIEW_MODE_GRIDVIEW** i.e., constant 1 which is equivalent to the constant value **MODE_WORLD_READABLE(1)** so you are getting that exception.

So, use different constant values

Reference: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_WORLD_READABLE